# How would i set the height and width of a noty notification

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, noty

Is there anyway to set the height and width of a noty notification.
Here is my code currently:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        noty({
            layout: 'topRight',
            type: 'alert',
            text: "<a href='C:\\Users\\dah\\Documents\\AlertJqueryNP\\alertjquery.html' target='_blank'>Alerts:"+count+"</a>",
            template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span></div>',
            closeWith: ['button'],
            dismissQueue: true, 
            timeout: false
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to set the width and height of .noty_message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with CSS. Whatever width and height you want, just set that in the CSS and it should work.

```
.noty-message{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: did not work for me, I put this on the top and bottom , don't know why no working, I am using notypackaged.js , I used  !important too with the css

Comment: @EdathadanChiefakaArun see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For org.webjars.bower.noty:3.1.4 layout is:

```
<div id="noty_layout__bottomRight" ....
</div>
```

noty.css

```
#noty_layout__bottomRight {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 325px;
}
```

To change width add in css:

```
#noty_layout__bottomRight {
   width: 350px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should force it to be 100px:

```
#noty_topRight_layout_container,
#noty_topRight_layout_container > li,
#noty_bar, #noty_type_alert           {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: I will test it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
.noty_layout > .noty_bar {
    height: 100px;
}
```